# How to create private hostzone on Route53 with Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-route53, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a private hostzone on route53, but looks like i'm seeing errors while creating/updating my cloudformation stack.

**Error**

```
17:35:41 UTC+0550  CREATE_FAILED   AWS::Route53::HostedZone    RancherRoute53HostedZone    Value of property VPCs must be of type List
```

**Cloudformation Template - YAML**

```
 RancherRoute53HostedZone:
    Properties:
      Name: 'test.com'
      VPCs:
        - 
          Ref: VPC
    Type : AWS::Route53::HostedZone
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** : In your example, as the error message indicates, you need to place the VPC ID inside a list [even if it is one]. That should solve the problem.

---

I see the CloudFormation Reference for Route 53 hosted zone and find that, if the parameter set includes the VPC id it results in creation of the private zone.

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::Route53::HostedZone",
  "Properties" : {
    "HostedZoneConfig" : { HostedZoneConfig },
    "HostedZoneTags" : [  HostedZoneTags, ... ],
    "Name" : String,
    "VPCs" : [ HostedZoneVPCs, ... ]   <---- Private Zone 
  }
}
```

More Info : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-hostedzone.html

Comment: That's not the problem.. The problem is the syntax is an object, like so `"VPCs" : [{
                        "VPCId"     : {"Ref" : "VPC"},
                        "VPCRegion" : {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}
                }]`